# Get and Post Request in c#

Tags: httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am making a post request with proper cookies in cookie container and proper post data(as I have checked it in IE developer tool) from my code but I am getting response string of some other page.

Can any one tell what may be the problem,I have wasted a lot of time so please give me an idea  that from where I have to start to diagnose. I am using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse in c#.

Comment: Please post some code snippet.

Comment: with no sample data posted we can just say try  again :)